# Failed commissioning because of false power on error

Tags: 16.04, maas

OS: UBUNTU 16.4

MAAS: 2.0.0 Beta 3

I Added new node to MAAS
After commissioning it gets Failed commissioning and says under node Latest machine events:

Failed to power on node - Node could not be powered on: Failed to complete power action: Failed to power query :

However it actually power on and of that nodes successfully!!

Answer (score 0):

Try powering down **ALL** hardware, and retrying. If it still fails, try reloading MAAS on both sides.

Comment: I tried , The result is same!

Answer (score 0):

I presume, you're using IPMI 2.0 power type. Go to MAAS > Nodes, click on node. Scroll down to Power, click Edit button, copy IP address, user and password. Then run the following command on your MAAS server:

```
ipmitool -I lanplus -H <ip address> -U <user> power status
```

and debug your way from there. It might be that you are actually missing IPMI user, have wrong password, mistyped IPMI IP or BMC is simply not accepting connections.

Comment: As I said, it power on the nodes actually, however it says in log it cant!

Comment: And that means that either MAAS is not getting the power status right or IPMI command it runs returns a non zero exit code. That's why you should debug what's exactly happening. 

Take a look at the class IPMIPowerDriver in src/provisioningserver/drivers/power/ipmi.py  and unit test test__issue_ipmi_command_issues_power_on() in  src/provisioningserver/drivers/power/tests/test_ipmi.py to get the idea how that could be done.

I admit, there might be no fun in doing this, but hey, at least it's open sourced, so your chances of dealing with an issue are good.